# SQL Uniqueidentifier and hashbytes does not match with c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, hashbytes

Creating hash with c# is different when same done in SQL server. why not same?

```
using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
{
    Guid g = new Guid("81FE483B-39ED-4052-8FFC-55A710907D9B");
    var appGateId = g.ToString();
    
    var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(appGateId));
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (byte b in hash)
    {
        sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Here the result is `ebb52fefab48f428b6ee03174276c8ade0b4ef1a`.

With SQL Server and this code:

```
declare @a uniqueidentifier = '81FE483B-39ED-4052-8FFC-55A710907D9B', @b nvarchar(50)

select @b = CONVERT(nvarchar(50), @a)
select convert(varchar(50), hashbytes('SHA1', @b), 2)
```

the result is `CC34B1E702F6E7FE0EE92ED4D5390BB4765B9A21`

Comment: i want hash creation in sql server should be same as created in c#

Comment: Computing the hash of the UTF8 of the string of a guid is *very* different to computing the hash of a guid; a guid is 16 bytes - you're hashing 36 bytes; then there's endianness to consider; the endianness of guids is... complex, and different system use different rules; but: if you're happy to use strings here: there's also case sensitivity; your TSQL version ends as upper case, the C# version ends as lower-case

Comment: ultimately: why hash at all here? the guid is **shorter**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@[Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell)'s comment explains the problem here. In C# you are using a UTF-8 string, but in SQL Server you're using a `nvarchar`, which is a UTF-16; these aren't comparable.

If you actually use a `varchar`, however, and change the characters to lowercase (as a `uniqueidentifier` is changed to uppercase when converted to a string based data type in T-SQL) you *do* get the same value. You could (if you're on 2019+) explicitly collate the value to a UTF-8 value too, but considering a GUID is made up of only hex characters (0-9A-F), this seems a little pointless:

```sql
DECLARE @a uniqueidentifier = '81FE483B-39ED-4052-8FFC-55A710907D9B', @b varchar(50);
SELECT @b = LOWER(CONVERT(varchar(50), @a));

SELECT @b, LOWER(CONVERT(varchar(50), HASHBYTES('SHA1', @b), 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

To get these to be equivalent, you have two issues:

- As mentioned, you are requesting UTF-8, and SQL Server is using UTF-16
- C# generates it in lower-case, SQL Server in upper-case

You could change the C# code

```cs
using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
{
    Guid g = new Guid("81FE483B-39ED-4052-8FFC-55A710907D9B");
    var appGateId = g.ToString().ToUpper().Dump();

    var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(appGateId));
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (byte b in hash)
    {
        sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7BHSE6)

Or you could change the SQL Server code

```
declare @a uniqueidentifier = '81FE483B-39ED-4052-8FFC-55A710907D9B', @b varchar(50)

select @b = LOWER(CONVERT(varchar(50), @a))
select convert(varchar(50), hashbytes('SHA1', @b COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8 ), 2)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9215efac3bc5e47a20e32d30ef05a65c)

---

To  be very honest, I don't understand why you are hashing the *string representation* anyway. You could just as easily hash the actual Guid bytes.